# Why "to"? Shouldn't it be "of"?

Tags: prepositions

In the Stargate franchise they use the preposition "*to*". Shouldn't it be "*of*"? *Mother **of** the leader and First Prime of Apophis*

From the [transcript](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/10.02_%22Morpheus%22_Transcript) on Stargate Wiki:

> LANDRY
>   (sighing):
>   As the former First Prime **to** Apophis, Teal'c provided valuable insight to the enemy's resources and tactics.
>   DANIEL:
>   And as the mother **to** the leader of the Ori army, Vala may hold the key to stopping them.

Comment: http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/10.02_%22Morpheus%22_Transcript

Comment: It's a *fantasy writing* context, so they're probably using non-standard prepositions to add to the sense of "exotic other-worldliness". Bear in mind that **First Prime** itself doesn't have any established meaning in English, so we're already well away with the fairies here.

Answer (score 1):

The usage is correct, but less common. Relationships can be represented by both 'of' and 'to'.

For example, "Helga is a mother to Nimitta" conveys Helga's relationship to Nimitta. It can also be conveyed as "Helga is a mother of Nimitta".

Comment: For me your second sentence doesn't work. I read "mother of" as implying biological parenthood, or possibly an adoptive parent. Even in the second case I doubt that the adoptee would consider that she had two 'real mothers', she would be more likely to refer to her 'mother' and her 'birth mother' so to say "a mother of" is inappropriate.  "Mother to" implies to me someone who is acting as a _mother figure_ to the subject and may well be one of a number of women in that position so "a mother to" is entirely reasonable. "The mother to" as quoted by the OP seems wrong by the opposite argument.

Comment: "To" is also used in relationships such as "adjutant to General Whatsit".

Comment: @HotLicks True, but the adjutant is not a biological parent (unless the General is indulging in reverse nepotism)

Answer (score 0):

The use of *to* where you are expecting *of* is unremarkable, just less common. It has been used in literature and law for more than a thousand years. A source and some examples follow.

*[New English Dictionary](https://archive.org/stream/oedxaarch#page/n95/mode/2up)*, volume TI–TZ, Oxford University Press, 1926 printing:

> **To**
>   **A.** *prep.* (in ordinary use, before a sb.)
>   **V.** Indicating addition, attachment, accompaniment, appurtenance, possession.
>   **17.** After *belong* and verbs of similar meaning (q.v.); also after *be* with the sense of *belong*; also after a sb., in the sense ‘appertaining or belonging to’: sometimes equivalent to ‘of’ or the possessive case of the sb.
>
> *c* **893** K. Æ<sub><sup>LFRED</sup></sub> *Oros. ɪ. i. § 21 Þæt Witland belimpeð to Estum.
>   **972** *Charter* in Birch *Cart. Sax.* III. 589 Ðis sind þa land ȝemæra þæs londes þe lympð to Sture.
>   **1451** *Rolls of Parlt.* V. 226/2 Godes … that were sumtyme to the seid William
>   *c* **1530** L<sub><sup>D</sup></sub>. B<sub><sup>ERNERS</sup></sub> *Arth. Lyt. Bryt.* 299, I am doughter to a king.
>   **1605** C<sub><sup>AMDEN</sup></sub> *Rem*. (1637) 281 Katherine, wife to Charles Brandon, Duke of Suffolke.
>   **1719** D<sub><sup>E</sup></sub> F<sub><sup>OE</sup></sub> *Crusoe* (1840) I. i. 2 Lieutenant-colonel to an English regiment of foot.
>   *Ibid.* 5 Clerk to an attorney.